# How to check that a Class is on Build Path when using Spring dependency injection

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, buildpath

I am using Spring for dependency injection. The context is configured by XML files. I am using Eclipse. Is there any way in Eclipse, how to check if the classes, used in the xml files when creating beans, are on the Build Path?

Example:

```
    <bean id="myBean" class="com.example.MyClass" />
```

How can I check that MyClass is on the Build Path in Eclipse?

Comment: If you're using the Eclipse Spring support, the Spring Beans editor will already do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to ClassPath, as classes are present in ClassPath(even jars are the part of classpath). Moreover I am not really sure about the question, if the classes are not there in your classpath, spring will give exception while trying to resolve those dependencies. However if you want to know the location where this class is defined that too in eclipse, just press control and click on the class. It should tell you from where eclipse is picking up this class file.

I hope that my understanding of the question is right and hence the answer is pretty close to what you were looking for.

Comment: I meant Build Path in Eclipse, which I understand as classpath. I know, I can point at the class with Ctrl, but I wanted some highlight. Some kind of mechanism, that would underline the class in the xml file when it is not known to Eclipse.

Comment: I am not really sure about eclipse, but I use STS for spring development. In STS there is a tab altogether which gives you the complete dependency graph and other information.

Answer (score 1):

Your project won't deploy correctly - check the logs.

But your ide if its any good, will alert you before then.

BUT even better you should have unit tests that reveal the error.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @chrylis in a comment, the STS bean config editor will issue a warning or error about referenced classes that don't exist. Note that sometimes a bean config file is not opened in the Spring Config editor automatically. If the editor doesn't have a tab at the bottom called "Namespaces" then it's not the Spring-specific editor. In that case, right-clcik on the file and choose **Open with** > **Spring Config Editor**.

Once you're in the Spring Config editor, a quick way to check is to put the cursor in a class name then press <kbd>F3</kbd> which should take you to the class definition if it's on the project build path.